# What are the usable minerals that can be found in our daily life?

Tags: mineralogy

Can anyone tell me what are the minerals that can found at home or something that can be seen in yard or in waste/trash bins.

Comment: I think you first have to specify just whose daily life you're talking about.  Mine is probably not the same as yours, and neither of us are likely to be the same as my mining engineer neighbor.

Answer (score 2):

This question is somewhat vague & broad. It almost looks like a homework question.

For starters, in the kitchen there's salt, NaCl.

In the bathroom, talcum powder, which is ground up talc.

In the garden shed there's fertilizers.

In the yard, soil contains a numerous minerals, which will differ from location to location because of different types of soil. Locations with sandy soils will contain silica.